# What did I do wrong to get this FIBONACCI error?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that I am having trouble with it. I have been working with this program for a day and did not work. The output came only letters, @ symbol and numbers. Here is the description of the program.

Generate a Fibonacci sequence. Each number in the Fibonacci series is the
sum of the two preceding numbers in the sequence. The first two numbers in the sequence are both 1. The
third number is 2, the fourth number is 3, the fifth number is 5, and the sixth number is 8. The program should
be able to return a specified amount in the fibo sequence. If a number is specified that is out of range, a -1
should be returned.

I have done the code and the runner code. My output will be similar to this.

1

1

2

3

5

8

89

987

10946

1346269

165580141

1836311903

1

1

1

-1

Here is my code

```
 public class Fibonacci
{
    int[] fibArray;
    public Fibonacci()
    {
        fibArray = new int[50];
        this.setFibo();
    }
    public void setFibo()
    {
        fibArray[0]=1;
        fibArray[1]=1;
        for(int idx = 2; idx<fibArray.length; idx++){
            fibArray[idx] = fibArray[idx-1] + fibArray[idx-2];
        }
    }
    public int[] getFibo()
    {
        return fibArray;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getFibo() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Here is my runner code.

```
 public class FibonacciRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fibArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,11,16,21,31,41,46,1,1,2,1,2,11};
        Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci();
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());
        System.out.println(fibo.getFibo());

    }
}
```

Comment: `getFibo` returns an array.  Array's `toString()` method produces your output.

Comment: I have changed my output code to System.out.println(fibo.toString()); but, I got an output of this: [I@15db9742

Comment: It looks like you've already learned how to iterate through an array using a for loop in setFibo.  Why not just do that again?

Comment: Sorry but, I don't understand what you are saying?